# python prediction model ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to handle unknown categorical variables in my dataset by using randomforestclassifier to predict the values for unknown categorical variables, but I am getting the error "could not convert string to float." Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

raw_data =      pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/CompSci_Projects/Stroke_Prediction_Model/dataset/healthcare-dataset-stroke-data.csv')
data = raw_data.copy(deep=True)
data.interpolate(method='linear', inplace = True)

x = data.drop(x_columns_to_drop, axis=1)
y = data.drop(y_columns_to_drop, axis=1)

smokestatus_unknown = data[data['smoking_status'] == 'Unknown']
smokestatus_known =  data[data['smoking_status'] != 'Unknown']

x_columns_to_drop = ['id', 'smoking_status']
y_columns_to_drop = ['id', 'gender', 'age', 'hypertension', 'heart_disease',    'ever_married', 'work_type', 'Residence_type', 'avg_glucose_level', 'bmi', 'stroke']

x_train = smokestatus_known.drop(x_columns_to_drop, axis=1)
y_train = smokestatus_known.drop(y_columns_to_drop, axis=1)

pre_test = data[data['smoking_status'] == 'Unknown']
x_test = pre_test.drop(x_columns_to_drop, axis=1)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train = x_train
X_test = x_test
Y_train = y_train

classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predicted_values = classifier.predict(X_test)

data.loc[data['smokingstatus'] == 'Unknown', 'smoking_status'] = predicted_values

data
```

And here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/2j/350ck5_15yg7p6_0p1lw6t500000gn/T/ipykernel_24490/3338127291.py in ?()
     20 Y_train = y_train
     21 
     22 # Train a RandomForestClassifier (you can choose other classifiers based on your preference)
     23 classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
---> 24 classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     25 
     26 # Predict missing values
     27 predicted_values = classifier.predict(X_test)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1147                 skip_parameter_validation=(
   1148                     prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1149                 )
   1150             ):
-> 1151                 return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in ?(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    344         """
    345         # Validate or convert input data
    346         if issparse(y):
    347             raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")
--> 348         X, y = self._validate_data(
    349             X, y, multi_output=True, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE
    350         )
    351         if sample_weight is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    617                 if "estimator" not in check_y_params:
    618                     check_y_params = {**default_check_params, **check_y_params}
    619                 y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    620             else:
--> 621                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    622             out = X, y
    623 
    624         if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1143         raise ValueError(
   1144             f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1145         )
   1146 
-> 1147     X = check_array(
   1148         X,
   1149         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1150         accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    914                         )
    915                     array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    916                 else:
    917                     array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
--> 918             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    919                 raise ValueError(
    920                     "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    921                 ) from complex_warning

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in ?(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    376         # Use NumPy API to support order
    377         if copy is True:
    378             array = numpy.array(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    379         else:
--> 380             array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    381 
    382         # At this point array is a NumPy ndarray. We convert it to an array
    383         # container that is consistent with the input's namespace.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, dtype)
   1996     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
   1997         values = self._values
-> 1998         arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
   1999         if (
   2000             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)
   2001             and using_copy_on_write()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

Comment: Could you please add the full error message with stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError indicates that there are non-numeric values in the data that the RandomForestClassifier is unable to handle A few things to try:

1)Check the data types of all the columns in your DataFrame. Make sure any categorical/string columns are properly encoded before modelling. You can use LabelEncoder() or OneHotEncoder() to convert categorical values to numerical ones.

2)Explicitly convert any string columns to numeric. For example:

data['column_name'] = data['column_name'].astype(float)

3)If there are null values in the data, fill or drop them first.

4)Double-check that your train and test data match all features.The error may come from a mismatch in columns/encoding between X_train and X_test.

5)Try handling the unknown categorical values differently - for example attributing the mode, mean, or a new category.